# How many cards will one draw, if more than one Arcane Missile hits the Acolyte of Pain?

Tags: hearthstone

[Arcane Missiles](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arcane_Missiles):

> This spell casts 3 individual missiles at randomly selected hostile characters.

[Acolyte of Pain](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Acolyte_of_Pain):

> Whenever this minion takes damage, draw a card.

1. I have an Acolyte with 3 life
2. Opposing player casts Arcane Missiles
3. Multiple projectiles hit my Acolyte

**How many cards will I draw?**

Comment: Not quite what was planned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will draw for each time the card is hit. Its ability activates each time it takes damage, not   the damage it's taken for the whole turn.

Comment: Notably, you draw before the rest of the missiles are fired. The triggered effect actually interrupts the Missiles' resolution.